# Test if MKAnnotationView is visible UI Automation iOS

Tags: ios, testing, instruments, mkannotationview, ios-ui-automation

All I would like to do is test if an MKAnnotationView on my map is hidden but when I find the UIAElement and call isVisible() on it, I always get 1 returned.
Is there a way to test if an MKAnnotationView is hidden or showing?